# How to implement sharding?

Tags: sql-server, sharding

First world problems: We've got a production system that is growing rapidly, and we are aiming to grow our user base even more.  At peak times our DB is flatlining at 100% CPU, which I take as an indication that it's pretty much stretched to the limit.  Being an AWS instance, we could always throw some more hardware at it, but long term, it seems we will need to implement sharding.

I've Googled all over and found lots of explanations of **what** sharding is, **why** it is a good idea under certain circumstances, **what** design considerations, etc... but not a word on the practicality of **how** to do it.

What are the practical steps to shard a database?  How do you redirect queries to the appropriate shard?  And how do you run reports that require data from all shards?

Comment: This question is too broad for SOs Q&A format.  I would suggest you start with Microsoft's article on [sharding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn589797.aspx).

Comment: @destination-data I also saw that article, but it's very light on implementation details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to decide is whether or not you want to take on the complexity of routing queries in your application. If you decide to roll your own implementation, there are a number of complexities that you'll need to deal with over time.

You'll need a scheme to distribute data and queries evenly across the cluster. You'll need to ensure that this scheme is forward-compatible with a larger cluster, as if your data is already big enough to require a sharded architecture, it's likely that you'll need to add more servers.

The problem with sharding schemes is that they force you to make tradeoffs that you wouldn't have to make with a single-server database. For example, if you are sharding by `user_id`, any query which spans multiple users will need to be sent to all servers (or a subset of servers) and the results must be accumulated in your client application. This is especially complex if you are using aggregate queries that rely on the ordering of the data, such as `MAX()`, or any histogram computation.

All of this complexity isn't meant to scare you, but it's something you'll need to pay attention to. There are tools out there that can help you (disclosure: my company makes a tool called [dbShards](http://www.dbshards.com/)) but you can definitely put together your own solution, especially if your application is mature and the query patterns are quite predictable.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the major thing I've learned between your answer and the other research I've done since posting the question is that there's really no out-the-box solution or standard architecture or software pattern for sharding, at least at this point in software development history; every project is going to be custom developed according to its particular domain.  I just wanted to be sure that I wasn't reinventing the wheel, but it turns out there isn't any standard "wheel" out there anyway.